# Headless Libre: Specify Sheets that should be converted into single PDF

Tags: libreoffice

Per [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30465397) I am able to convert .xlsx to a PDF using the following command on the command line: (linux system)

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice \
    --headless \
    --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export \
    --outdir /path/to/destination \
    --infilter="Microsoft Excel 2007/2010 XML" \
    /path/to/file.xlsx
```

However, this will only generate a single sheet. The original Excel file contains multiple sheets and I seem to be unable to select the desired sheets that should be in the final PDF.

**Goal**:

The Excel contains multiple Sheets that are in order. I want to exclude the first sheet and include all remaining ones into a single PDF.

Bonus: Each sheet should be on a single page.

Comment: Not sure if you will achieve the desired result this way. The task is too complex and peculiar, there are too few command line parameters for free maneuvering. Perhaps a simpler way to solve the problem would be to write a macro with one parameter (the name of the source .xlsx file) and call exactly this macro from the command line, as [**demonstrated here**](https://superuser.com/a/1136187/1586123)

Comment: I convert xlsx to pdf with `libreoffice --nolockcheck --headless --convert-to pdf ./test.xlsx`. To exclude specific sheets from that export I'm hiding that sheets. In some cases I hide them manually in LibreOffice, in some other cases I hide them automatically with Apache POI (Java library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I ended up with the following way:

1. Convert via headless libre
2. Remove undesired pages via [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

The templates are fixed and we know explicitly which pages to remove.